# Unsupported Project Type Xamarin Store T-Shirt tutorial

Tags: xamarin

I'm trying to get up and running with Xamarin and I've downloaded the tutorial t-shirt app from their site. When I open it in VS 2013 (update 2) the XamarinStore project in the solution can't load. It says the project type is unsupported.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the latest Xamarin but still can't get it to work. Did anyone else have this issue? Any ideas how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My VS 2013 installation was poked. Reinstalled and all working now.

*whistles*